# powershell: importing csv as an array of bytes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create stored credentials for a script to run on multiple machines.  I can get it to work on my machine just fine but am aware that I need to have a custom key for convertto-securestring if i want to run it on other computers.  I saved the key as both a csv and .txt.
The issue is that when I try to read the key from the file to a variable and use it with ConvertTo-SecureString , it errors out.  Is it possible to take a csv and save it to a variable as an array of bytes?

`$encrypted = get-content .\Documents\powershell\encrypted_pass1.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. To create my key, I used the system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider::create() method.
and the -encoding byte parameter of set-content and get-content. 
Code example follows.

```
#Generate encryption key.
$key = New-Object byte[](32)
$rng = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create()
$rng.GetBytes($key)
set-content -path ./key.txt -value $key -encoding byte
```

And to decrypt and use it..

```
$decryptkey = get-content -Encoding byte -Path .\key.txt
$encrypted = get-content .\securepassword.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $decryptkey
$decryptptr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($encrypted)
$decrypted = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($decryptptr)
```

Hope that helps.

-Rich

Comment: whoops, that decrypt code is jacked up. I'll try one more time. See if this looks right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$Encrypted = Get-Content -Encoding Byte -Path .\Documents\PowerShell\encrypted_pass1.txt;
```

Comment: Hey Trevor,
Thanks for the input - I think I worded my question poorly but I understand your response and how it relates.  It brought up another question however that is probably the core of the issue: how do you save a byte array to file?  for instance if i wanted to save a 192 bit key to a file for use on other machines.  I think that is where my primary issue is - I am trying to just save it to as a txt file

Comment: The "key" is just text, right? Use the `Set-Content` cmdlet to save information to a file. `Set-Content -Path c:\key.txt -Value 'mykeyvalue';`

Comment: this is an example of what I have in key.txt
**165,21,193,254,46,198,192,217,116,204,44,240,36,48,80,118,208,68,32,157,190,35,102,70** 
I could save this manually as a variable, $key = 165,21,...70 and then reuse it with **convertto-SecureString -key $key**